# Subdomain from folder in Apache (MAMP install)

Tags: .htaccess, mamp, domain-name

I have a MAMP install, on OS X Mountain Lion, it works well. No issues with the MAMP, just the .htaccess of my site

I added a domain, www.mycity1.localhost which is added to the HOSTS file, and the site works well.

How would I create a subdomain from the folders, as I have three folders:

london

manchester

norwich

Rather than having http://www.mycity1.localhost/london, how could I get the URL to be http://london.mycity1.localhost (and the other examples).

I have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
```

but am not sure how to do this exactly.

These are all stored in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www.mycity1.localhost as the directory.

Any help is appreciated, as it will be useful for when I actually move these to my proper site online (offline at the moment).

- Note, these domains despite being hyperlinked will **not** work, as they are (obviously) localhost-only.